# Div disappears after inserting php code

Tags: php, html

I have two DIVs which are floating side by side correctly but after embedding the php code as below, the whole page will not show anything. Even When I remove the php code, the page will not show again. The code below is for the div that floats right.

```
<div style="float:right;">
        <?php
            echo "<div>
                    <head>
                        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='chatbox/style/cb_style.css'>
                        <script type='text/javascript' src='chatbox/ajax.js'></script>
                        <script type='text/javascript' src='chatbox/chatbox.js'></script>
                    </head>
                <div>";
            ?>

            <div id="container">
                <div id="usersOnLine">
                    <div style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:35%;">Online Users</div>
                    <div style="height:82%;">
                        <?php
                            if (!empty($friends)) {
                                foreach ($friends as $friend) {
                                    $friend_name = htmlentities($user['username'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
                                    echo "<span>{$friend_name}</span>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <input type='text' placeholder='search' style='width:145px;'/><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="chat_search">
                    <un>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you write :
`$friend_name = htmlentities($friend['username'], ENT_NOQUOTES);`
instead of :
`$friend_name = htmlentities($user['username'], ENT_NOQUOTES);`

We cannot see where $user comes from, so maybe PHP doesn't either... (?)

Comment: "after embedding the php code as below, the whole page will not show anything. Even When I remove the php code, the page will not show again." - so the obvious question is: what else have you changed?

Comment: @poozlax : Thanx for the contribution. I have corrected the issues you raised. Still it doesnt like my php code

Comment: @Horvath: I just reaised its the SQL function inside the php function i am using to fetch friends from the DB, as well as all the points raised by poozlax and Chad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding a `<head>` element into the DOM, you should remove that surrounding `div` and `head` and place that first chunk of php code inside your page's `<head>` section. The browser is getting confused when you introduce a new `<head>` element that way.

EDIT: to explain further, with a possible example...

You can add those new stylesheet and js entries into your `head` by appending them to your header include (assuming you are using an include for your main html header - in this example, we call it "header.php", since that's common)

```php
<?php 
    $addme = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chatbox/style/cb_style.css">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="chatbox/ajax.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="chatbox/chatbox.js"></script></head>';
    ob_start(); // start a buffer
    include("header.php"); 
    $contents = ob_get_contents(); // buffer the contents of header.php
    ob_end_clean(); // end & clean the buffer

    // replace the closing tag with the added stuff
    echo str_replace('</head>', $addme, $contents);

?>
```

Comment: I changed things around but the php somehow is causing the problem

Comment: I'd suggest answering Karoly Horvath's comment on your question... He raises an excellent point.